# Multivariate FindGeneratingFunction

Tags: series-expansion

For one dimensional problems sometimes I'm using the Mathematica function `FindGeneratingFunction[seriescoefficient,x]` which uses the coefficients of a powerseries expansion to calculate the generating function f[x].

Is there an extension for multivariate functions ? Thanks!